# Как получить измененный текст в richtextBox?

Tags: c#

Имеется richTextBox. Там уже присутствует некая запись. Далее я меняю эту запись нажимаю Enter или кнопку "OK" и нужно этот новый текст сохранить в строку. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Похожая проблема: [RichTextBox (WPF) does not have string property “Text”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text)

```
string myText = new TextRange(transcriberArea.Document.ContentStart,
                              transcriberArea.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

Comment: Включите информацию по ссылке в ответ, пожалуйста. Ссылки имеют свойство протухать.